# "apt full-upgrade" returns "1 not fully installed or removed."

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I tried to uninstall two earlier versions of Java by merely removing the files, but now got this error and don't know how to solve. What's the issue/solution?

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/583 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

```
$ sudo dpkg -C
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 npm                  package manager for Node.js
The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 npm                  package manager for Node.js
```

Comment: What did you get after answering `Y`?

Comment: Try `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

Comment: frederick@frederickpina:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/583 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
frederick@frederickpina:~$

Comment: What is the output of `dpkg -C`?

Comment: frederick@frederickpina:~$ sudo dpkg -C
[sudo] password for frederick: 
The following packages are in a mess due to serious problems during
installation.  They must be reinstalled for them (and any packages
that depend on them) to function properly:
 npm                  package manager for Node.js

The following packages are missing the md5sums control file in the
database, they need to be reinstalled:
 npm                  package manager for Node.js

frederick@frederickpina:~$

Answer (score 3):

First, update `apt` to make sure the latest version matches your update list:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then, reinstall `npm` to replace any missing files:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" npm
```

Uninstalling packages by deleting files is dangerous. `npm` is for javascript, not java. If you need help uninstalling java, I strongly suggest asking a separate question for advice on how to properly uninstall.

The `Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss"` option replaces any missing configuration files.